# Required parameter not present despite being in json encoding

Tags: java, swift, http, spring-boot, alamofire

I am sending a http post request from a swift using alamofire:

```
let url = userActivity.webpageURL

    if(url?.description.contains(UniversalLinkHandler().urlPrefix))!
    {
        let keystore = try! EtherKeystore()
        let signedOrder = UniversalLinkHandler().parseURL(url: (url?.description)!)
        let signature = signedOrder.signature.substring(from: 2)
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "address" : keystore.recentlyUsedWallet?.address.description,
            "indices": signedOrder.order.indices,
            "v" : signature.substring(from: 128),
            "r": signature.substring(from: 0, to: 64),
            "s": signature.substring(from: 64, to: 128)
        ]
        let query = UniversalLinkHandler.paymentServer

        Alamofire.request(
                query,
                method: .post,
                parameters: parameters
        ).responseJSON {
            result in
            print(result)
        }
    }
```

The indices appear as a normal UInt16 array in the debugger however when sent to the server it says the indices array is not present

The server is in java and uses springboot:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/claimToken", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity getAToken(@RequestParam(value="address") String address,
                                @RequestParam(value="indices") int[] indices,
                                @RequestParam(value = "v") byte v,
                                @RequestParam(value = "r") String r,
                                @RequestParam(value = "s") String s
)
```

The first param address works just fine but it doesn't work with the int[] array of indices

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `signedOrder.order.indices`?

Comment: [UInt16] array in swift

Answer (score 0):

As it is your `signedOrder.order.indices` array which is causing you the problem, and this is of type `[UInt16]`, my recommendation would be:

```
let indices = signedOrder.order.indices.map(Int.init)
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "address" : keystore.recentlyUsedWallet?.address.description,
            "indices": indices,
            "v" : signature.substring(from: 128),
            "r": signature.substring(from: 0, to: 64),
            "s": signature.substring(from: 64, to: 128)
        ]
```

Mapping to `Int` may well solve your issue.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Also since it is being encoded into javascript (JSON notation) it shouldn't matter if it is UInt16 or Int... Thanks though